# Can not get the instance of a singleton class from other classes

Tags: c++, class, include

The problem I am facing is somehow related to "loop inclusion" or "incompleted class"

I have 2 classes:

**ControllerManager**, this class is declared as Singleton, this class has a object of *AuxController*.

**AuxController**, this class has a function that needs to get the instance of *ControllerManager*

The problem is: when compiling source code, it fails with error "incomplete type" or "invalid type"

Is there any way to fix this problem?
or is there any other way to redesign code structure?

**Source code**
ControllerManager.h

```
#ifndef CONTROLLERMANAGER_H
#define CONTROLLERMANAGER_H
#include "auxcontroller.h"

class ControllerManager
{
/* This class is defined as Singleton class */
private:
    /* 1. define a private static instance */
    static ControllerManager *inst;

public:
    /* 2. define a public static accessor */
    static ControllerManager *getInstance(){
        /* 3. do lazy initialization */
        if(!inst){
            inst = new ControllerManager();
        }
        return inst;
    }

protected:
    /* 4. Define all accessors to be protected */
    ControllerManager();
    ~ControllerManager();

/* property */
private:
    int m_code;

public:
    int getCode()
    {
        return m_code;
    }

    void setCode(int _code)
    {
        m_code = _code;
    }

/* below code causes fail of compilation */
public:

    AuxController m_auxcontroller;

};

#endif // CONTROLLERMANAGER_H
```

ControllerManager.cpp

```
#include "controllermanager.h"

/* 5. initialize static variable */
ControllerManager *ControllerManager::inst = 0;
ControllerManager::ControllerManager()
{
    m_code = 15;
}

ControllerManager::~ControllerManager()
{
    delete inst;
}
```

AuxController.h

```
#ifndef AUXCONTROLLER_H
#define AUXCONTROLLER_H

/* if do NOT include controllermanager.h with below line,
 * and declare ControllerManager class as a forward declaration:
 *
 * class ControllerManager;
 *
 * compiler will stop due to "incomplete type"
 */
#include "controllermanager.h"



class AuxController
{
public:
    AuxController();
    void setControllerCode(int code);
};

#endif // AUXCONTROLLER_H
```

AuxController.cpp

```
#include "auxcontroller.h"

AuxController::AuxController()
{

}

void AuxController::setControllerCode(int code)
{
    /* if do NOT include controllermanager.h ,
     * and declare ControllerManager class as a forward declaration in the header file:
     *
     * class ControllerManager;
     *
     * compiler will stop due to "incomplete type" at this line
     *
     */
    ControllerManager::getInstance()->setCode(code);
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "controllermanager.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ControllerManager *ctlMng = ControllerManager::getInstance();
    ctlMng->setCode(10);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please put the error messages verbatim in your question. I'd suspect you have a circular include problem or such, the error message is a typical symptom of such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not include "controllermanager.h" inside auxcontroller.h, but do include it inside auxcontroller.cpp.

In general you should not include header files by other header files if it can be avoided. Use forward declaration instead. But do include all required header files from cpp files.

Comment: This: also even if you have to forward declare you have to include the header in the cpp file anyway.

Comment: You are welcome, please accept the answer if it fixed your problem.

Answer (score 2):

The problem consists into a *cycle dependency*.

In order to solve that problem: use [forward declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757565/c-forward-declaration) and include all needed header only in the *cpp* (compilation-unit) file.

In *ControllerManager.hpp*:

```
class AuxController;

class ControllerManager {
  // ...
  public: AuxController* m_auxcontroller;
};

// Remember to not use m_auxcontroller in the header file, JUST declaration are allowed.
```

*Note:* you have to use *pointers* or *references* to the forwarded class, so remember to initialize them correctly.

In the *ControllerManager.cpp*:

```
#include "ControllerManager.hpp"
#include "AuxController.hpp"  // In Cpp file include everything you need.
// ...
```

---

The same in the class `AuxController`.

In the *AuxController.hpp*:

```
// You dont need header of other file in this case.

class AuxController {
  // ...
};
```

In *AuxController.cpp*:

```
#include "AuxController.hpp"
#include "ControllerManager.hpp"

// ...
```

Comment: From my understanding this will not compile since you are not using a pointer to the forward declared class `AuxController`. `m_auxcontroller` must either be a pointer or reference.

Comment: @TheBadger You're right, too fast! I'm going to fix that